# Convert string into TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan

How to convert `1` `1,5` `2` `2,5` `3` `3,5` into `TimeSpan` in C#?

1 would be `01:00`
1,5 would be `01:30` 
2 would be `02:00` 
2,5 wouble be `02:30`

I've already tried

```
string myTime = "1";
TimeSpan finalTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(myTime, "hh:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

But I get the following error

> Incorrect input string format.

Comment: How does `hh:mm` fit the `1` or `1.5` values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string myTime = "1,5";
TimeSpan finalTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(Double.Parse(myTime));
```

Output:

01:30:00

Comment: Note: You probably want to make sure first that the current culture's decimal separator is a comma and not a dot.

Comment: @funie200: [A timespan has not format.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)